# Rails 3 - Some Required JS Not Being Found

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, prototypejs

I moved a Rails 2.2.2 site to Rails 3 and have been fixing it as I go. I am now onto the JS portion of the site and I am seeing the following when I hit a page that includes JS:

[image]

Could this be a cascade issue? - controls.js is being loaded before effects.js I would think Rails would handle this under the hood somehow?

Here is the order the JS is being loaded:

```
Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1"
Served asset /jquery.js - 200 OK (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/jquery-ui.js?body=1"
Served asset /jquery-ui.js - 200 OK (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/jquery.alerts.js?body=1"
Served asset /jquery.alerts.js - 200 OK (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1"
Served asset /jquery_ujs.js - 200 OK (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/admin.js?body=1"
Served asset /admin.js - 200 OK (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/controls.js?body=1"
Served asset /controls.js - 200 OK (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/dragdrop.js?body=1"
Served asset /dragdrop.js - 200 OK (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/effects.js?body=1"
Served asset /effects.js - 200 OK (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/jquery.validate.min.js?body=1"
Served asset /jquery.validate.min.js - 200 OK (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/prototype.js?body=1"
Served asset /prototype.js - 200 OK (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1"
Served asset /application.js - 200 OK (3ms)


Started GET "/assets/jquery-ui.css?body=1"
Served asset /jquery-ui.css - 200 OK (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/jquery.alerts.css?body=1"
Served asset /jquery.alerts.css - 200 OK (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/default.css?body=1"
Served asset /default.css - 200 OK (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1"
Served asset /jquery.js - 200 OK (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/jquery-ui.js?body=1"
Served asset /jquery-ui.js - 200 OK (0ms)
```

The file **application.js** looks like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks Much!

**/app/assets/javascript**

[image]

Comment: Did you install both jquery-rails and prototype-rails gems? That will cause problems in the asset pipeline. Only install one and give it a try.

Comment: @Ken I have neither installed - I have a feeling that these JS files were just put into the public folder when it was running on Rails 2. Do I need one of these gems in order for JS dependencies to be found?

Comment: Yes - install either one and give it a try.

Comment: @Ken Did "gem install prototype-rails" and restarted - Same errors in FireBug.

Comment: Did you follow the installation instructions? https://github.com/rails/prototype-rails If you're new to the asset pipeline, read the docs. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: @Ken I will more read about asset pipeline but in the meantime I looked at application.js - Perhaps application.js is incomplete? All I see is this: //= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs Shouldn't all of the JS files from the above screenshot be listed in application.js?
//= require_tree .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the load order in application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require prototype/prototype
//= require prototype/effects
//= require prototype/dragdrop
//= require prototype/controls
//= require_tree .
```